# Taking screenshot using selenium/python/shell script using http authentication

Tags: python, selenium, http, authentication, screenshot

I working on something like below. I have web application which accepts Username and password. Now my requirements is to write a program:

- Login to that web application with port. For example.

  http://abecdefgh:1101
- And then in that main page, there will be Username and Password Fiedls and a OK button.
- I need to fill username and password and login
- once its login into application, there will be one text tab called buckets, I need to click on that, it will show item count and so on...
- Now I need screen capture (screenshot) now and save it to some location

Is there any way I can do that with shell scripting / python

Any guidance is highly appreciated

Update1:

Tried below selenium code:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Downloadsnew\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get("http://xxxxx:1091/ui/index.html")

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("login_inp")
elem.send_keys("Administrator")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("password2_inp")
elem.send_keys("password")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
elem.click()
#elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='line']")
#elem1.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@mn-tab='buckets']").click()
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='line' and text()='buckets']").click()
```

. But find element by xpath is not working

the below is inspect data for that bucket tab:

```
<div id="headerNav">
<div class="contents">
  <ul mn-pluggable-ui-tabs="" mn-tab-bar-name="adminTab">
    <li mn-tab="overview" class="line currentNav" ui-sref-active="currentNav">
      <a ui-sref="app.admin.overview" href="#/overview">Overview</a>
    </li>
    <li mn-tab="servers" class="line" ui-sref-active="currentNav">
      <a class="switch_servers" ui-sref="app.admin.servers.list" href="#/servers/active">Server Nodes</a>
    </li>
    <li mn-tab="buckets" class="line" ui-sref-active="currentNav">
      <a class="switch_buckets" ui-sref="app.admin.buckets" href="#/buckets">Data Buckets</a>
    </li><li ng-show="admin.internal.all" class="line ng-scope" ui-sref-active="currentNav"><a ui-sref="app.admin.query.workbench" class="ng-binding" href="#/query/workbench">Query</a></li>
```

Comment: Use [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#python).

Comment: Hi tried below code with selenium

Comment: Do you need help to find the element or with Screenshot?

Comment: Yes Kamal, I need to find that bucket tab and click on it. First I need to find bucket and click on it to open that page and then take screenshot and save it to some locations path. Currently struggling with finding that elements. In above post I posted inspect of that tab page. Do you get some insight what I need to do

Comment: Please try `driver.find_element_by_class_name('switch_buckets').click()`

Comment: Thanks it got worked...